# How to search in xml using solr?

Tags: xml, solr

I have XML data indexed in solr, for example:

```xml
<doc>
    <str name="arg1">These services</str>
    <str name="arg1_exact">These services</str>
    <str name="arg2">the Owings Mills campus</str>
    <str name="arg2_exact">the Owings Mills campus</str>
    <str name="namespace">reverb</str>
    <str name="rel">are located at</str>
    <str name="rel_exact">are located at</str>
    <float name="conf_f">0.936</float>
    <str name="id">reverb-273062579</str>
    <int name="num_extrs_i">2</int>
    <arr name="corpora_ss">
      <str>cw</str>
    </arr>
    <long name="_version_">1523088036550672385</long></doc>
<doc>
```

I have many such XML documents. I want to search for specific fields eg `arg1 = These services`. I would like to also allow searchers to do logical combinations of those.

I followed [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565521/can-solr-or-lucene-be-used-for-searching-xml), but it didn't help me.
Can anyone help?

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at solr query syntax https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax.

You might also want to look at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters which gives information on how an input query is analyzed. The analyzer is configured in schema.xml inside the solr core under "conf" directory

For instance,

http://:8983/solr//select?q=arg1:These AND arg1:Services or for a phrase search, http://:8983/solr//select?q=arg1:"These Services"